# Typescript reversing argument order

Tags: javascript, typescript

Reversing a functions argument order is quite straight forward, but inferring a type for the reversed function seems to be quite difficult (or not possible hence the question).

Given this (non-ts) code

```
const flip = (fn) => function() {
  return fn(...Array.from(arguments).reverse());
};
```

I'm trying to find a way to type the returned wrapping function to have the arguments of `fn` in reverse. I can't seem to find a way to do this and couldn't find any documentation on it.

Example:

```
export const flip = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T) =>
    (...args: any[]) => fn(...Array.from(args).reverse());
```

Rightly, the returned type is of `(...args: any[]) => T`

Is there a way that I can remove `(...args:any[]) => fn(...);` that'll allow TS to understand that the argument order for the wrapping function is just a reversed array of the inner functions arguments?

Comment: Nope, not possible. You might be able to do it for a limited numeber of arguments and you will have issues with rest and optional parameters.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I thought that might be the case, so my best bet is to keep it as it is. Thanks.

Comment: I believe general solution is not possible, and what people do in a case like this is a set of signatures for all meaningful cases, e.g. 10 signatures for functions with 0 to 9 arguments.

Comment: @alx exactly what I was suggesting.. Maybe it did not come across as I intended. 

Comment: @alx Right, I wonder how that would work with rest and optional params without having !n signature cases. Or am I interpreting this wrongly?

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/zip.ts -- it does not do what you want, but it shows how to overload signature.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can flip rest args. I mean, it does not make much sense?

Comment: Ha that's a really good point, didn't think that through 100%. Anyway thanks for the pointers and links.

Answer (score 0):

The function argument list is a `Tuple` so you need to cast it back to the correct `Tuple` type after calling `Array.reverse` on it.

```js
const reverse = <A extends Array<any>>(a: A): Reverse<A> =>
  (a.reverse() as unknown) as Reverse<A>;

type Flip = <A extends Array<any>, R>(f: (...a: A) => R) => (...a: Reverse<A>) => R;
const flip: Flip = (fn) => (...args) => fn(...(reverse(args) as any));

const getArgs = <A extends Array<any>>(...args: A): A => args;
const reversed: [string, string, null, number] = flip(getArgs)(1, null, 'bar', 'foo');
```

Answerd updated based on feedback from typescript-tuple developers. See https://github.com/ksxnodemodules/typescript-tuple/issues/12 for full discussion.